# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I want to get a category section from Firebase Firestore so I used this class

```
class CategoryModel {
  late String name, image;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
  });

  CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) {
      return;
    }

    name = map['name'];
    image = map['image'];
  }

  toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'image': image,
    };
  }
}
```

and then I created this with gets

```
class HomeViewModel extends GetxController {
  ValueNotifier<bool> get loading => _loading;
  ValueNotifier<bool> _loading = ValueNotifier(false);

  List<CategoryModel> get categoryModel => _categoryModel;
  List<CategoryModel> _categoryModel = [];

  HomeViewModel() {
    getCategory();
  }
  getCategory() async {
    _loading.value = true;
    await HomeService().getCategory().then((value) {
      for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        _categoryModel.add(
          CategoryModel.fromJson(
            value[i].data(),
          ),
        );
        
        _loading.value = false;
      }
      update();
    });
  }
}
```

but when I try to get categories from Firestore with the function getCategory() this error comes

[Error in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrU48.png)

[Error in Problems scetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYYoL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way and tell me if it's fixed.

```dart
CategoryModel.fromJson(
            value[i].data() as Map<String,dynamic>,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [Cloud Firestore 2.0 here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/).

The basic idea is that wherever you are trying to read the data from a DocumentSnapshot, you need to cast the Object? to Map<String, dynamic>.

You can do this in a few ways.

1. Cast the Object? to Map<String, dynamic> in your toJson method

```
    CategoryModel.fromJson(
         value[i].data() as Map<String,dynamic>,
    ),
```

2. Specify the type in your constructors

```
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> documentReference;
```

3. Specify the type in your StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                stream: model.testSnap,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Container();
                },
              )
```